# How to ignore -stdlib=libc++ for a specific file

Tags: c++, osx-yosemite, clang++

I have a project that compile with clang using

> `-stdlib=libc++`

and i want to  to ignore this flag for a file. is there any #pragma to use ?

i'm using clang6.0 under MacOS X Yosemite.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I doubt it's possible, why not instead use different command line arguments for that file?

Comment: Why exactly do you want to ignore this for a specific file?

Comment: This should be solved on the makefile level, not on the source level.

Comment: I thought it will be better to manage it from file level. i'm using qmake project that compile with -stdlib=libc++ option and i have some sources from an external lib which use tr1 directly